# How can I bind a directive to a column cell in angular-ui-grid?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

First, this is what I'm trying to do: I am using ngResource to grab an array of data from an API and setting the ui-grid's data to the array. One of the columns is an ID that has no meaning to the user. I would like to use another API to look up the meaning of that ID and get the human-friendly result of that. Before using ui-grid, I was simply using a directive that took that ID and set the element's text as the return result from the secondary API.

I know that it's possible to bind a column dynamically to data in that row's object, having looked at: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/106_binding, but it appears that this is limited to binding to the data in $scope or in the grid's data (such as in the example). I also see that there is a `cellClass` options method which allows conditional setting of the cell's class. However, I do not see any good options for intercepting the element in the cell and replacing it with a result of my choosing.

I am wondering what the best way to do this is. I've tried using ngResource's `transformResponse` but the array is too large to make a blocking event. As well, I've tried to inject the html for the directive into the `field`'s return function, i.e. `field: transformToHtml()` but only the raw string shows, not the rendered html.

Comment: As an aside, another use case that might become needed by users sooner than later is including tooltips and other elements to cells.

Comment: Have you looked at getExternalScopes() function?  You can specify an 'external-scopes' object that has your custom functions and then call them in your cells via getExternalScopes().MyFunc().  You will need to write your own cell template, however.